# Excel List Top Occurring Numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I've search but haven't found an example that finds the top 3 occurring numbers in a list. Most code is for text, top scoring or top 3 biggest values.

I have a list of orders with part numbers and prices that occurred during the year.

> -A---------B---------C-------D-------E
>       60470     $58
>       60470     $58
>       89038     $60
>       31859     $37
>       60470     $58
>       29079     $78
>       35568     $40
>       82677     $92
>       69172     $37
>       31859     $37
>       89038     $60
>       31859     $37
>       31859     $37
>       60470     $58
>       31859     $37
>       60470     $58
>       31859     $37

Column A has the part numbers and Column B has the prices. In Column D I would like to list the top 3 most occurring part numbers from column A and then then in Column E the sum total from all their occurrences.

In the example above, Column D and E would show the following respectively:

31859 $222.00
60470 $290.00
89038 $120.00

I really can't sort or add "helper" columns so I am trying to accomplish this using an array formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `D1`, **array formula****:

`=INDEX(A$1:A$17,MATCH(LARGE(IF(FREQUENCY(A$1:A$17,A$1:A$17),FREQUENCY(A$1:A$17,A$1:A$17)+ROW(A$1:A$17)/10^6),ROWS($1:1)),FREQUENCY(A$1:A$17,A$1:A$17)+ROW(A$1:A$17)/10^6,0))`

In `E1`:

`=SUMIF(A$1:A$17,D1,B$1:B$17)`

Regards

Comment: Thank you XOR LX. This works great. I do, however, have a question. If I extend this to view the "top 5" why does it repeat the part number 29079 for 4th and 5th place?

Comment: Apologies. Solution was flawed. Have amended, though note that an array formula is required after all.

Answer (score 0):

To get the part numbers, use

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$17,MATCH(LARGE(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$17,$A$1:$A$17),ROWS($1:1)),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$17,$A$1:$A$17),0))
```

This is an array formula, so you must use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when you input it in the formula bar, not just press ENTER

Once you've got the part numbers, a simple `SUMIF` gets the totals

Comment: Thank you emjaySX, however, when I drag the code down for the top 3, it repeats the same part number 31859.